# How to change "DestinationName" property of UNION ALL Transformation in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to make friendly names of Union All inputs; however, the Destination Name is dimmed.

I have 10+ inputs and it is really annoying finding the destination "Union All Input 10"

The best solution I could find so far is add Path Annotation as displayed in the picture below:
[image]

I want to rename Union All Input 1 to somthing meaningful.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has stated that they [Won't Fix This](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/543836/ssis-rename-inputs-on-union-all-component).  Bummer.  I have needed more descriptive names myself.

Comment: @Thanks Troy. Please post it as the answer with suggestion to upvote on the Microsoft site so it might be implemented at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft has stated that they [Won't Fix This](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/543836/ssis-rename-inputs-on-union-all-component). Bummer. Everyone please upvote the Microsoft Connect link and maybe they will assign a developer.

Answer (score -1):

Edit it in the XML Code, like so:

```
<input refId="{}" hasSideEffects="true" name="YOUR NEW NAME HERE">
```